# Mini webradio: doesn't play automatically

Tags: shutdown, cron

The setup is quite simple: a Raspberry, an ethernet cable and two old PC speakers; all of that is in my bedroom. The idea is to have a headless system that plays a music stream from a single "hardcoded" station and ahutdown after 90 minutes.

**Step 1**
The first thing was to install mplayer with the apt; then I checked with
`/usr/bin/mplayer -stream_URL-` 
and the speaker sounds (maybe I played a bit with the alsa mixer, I don't remember).

**Step 2**

`sudo nano audiostream.service`

with the content

```
Description=Start Mune Radio
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mplayer -stream_URL-
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and finally I enabled it for every boot: `sudo systemctl enable audiostream.service`

**Step 3**
I made it to reboot saying that in the root's crontab:

````
root@audiopi:~# crontab -e

[...]
@reboot  shutdown -h +90pi@audiopi:/etc/systemd/system $ sudo su -

root@audiopi:~# crontab -e

[...]
@reboot  shutdown -h +90```

Now I boot and it doesn't play: anybody has a hint?
Thanks
````

Comment: You should not need a @reboot cronjob; you already have a systemd service.

Comment: Your .service file is missing the `[Unit]` section header. Does `sudo systemctl start audiostream.service` start the player? And, once started, does `sudo systemctl stop audiostream.service` stop the player?

Comment: @user535733 I copy+pasted+slite_modified so I was worried to introduce errors, once it works, I'll do.
@user535733 ```systemctl status audiostream.service``` says that the service is down because ```ago 27 17:17:11 audiopi systemd[1]: audiostream.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
\n [time] audiopi systemd[1]: audiostream.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.```

Comment: Now you know two things: 1) Your .service fails to start, and 2) your `Restart=` line is spamming systemd with retries (not helping). For #1, try `systemctl status audiostream.service` to see the error messages about *why* it failed. For #2, consult https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html and pick a better Restart option.

Comment: Non my server is 
```  GNU nano 3.2                                           /etc/systemd/system/audiostream.service                                                       

[Unit]
Description=Start Mune Radio
Requires=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart="/home/pi/mywebradio.sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```
(the [Unit] header was already there, it was a cut&paste issue).

Comment: The ```shutdown``` went back in root's crontab as systemctl was complying about two commands (even if the guide says that they have just to be separated by a ```;``` ) then it said the mplayer was a simlink so I wrapped in the a script and now the status says:
```

Comment: **Too long: cut **
- Resolving icy.unitedradio.it for AF_INET...
- mywebradio.sh[316]: Couldn't resolve name for AF_INET: icy.unitedradio.it
- mwr.sh Failed, exiting.
- mwr.sh Resolving icy.unitedradio.it for AF_INET6...
- mwr.sh Couldn't resolve name for AF_INET6: icy.unitedradio.it
- mwr.sh Resolving icy.unitedradio.it for AF_INET...
- mwr.sh Couldn't resolve name for AF_INET: icy.unitedradio.it
- mwr.sh No stream found to handle url http://icy.unitedradio.it/VirginRockClassics.mp3
- mywebradio.sh[316]: Exiting... (End of file)```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112364/discussion-between-federico-munerotto-and-user535733).

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the help of user535733.

**Step 1**

Install mplayer `sudo apt install mplayer`

**Step 2**

Enable service, because otherwise mplayer can't connect to stream:

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
```

**Step 3**

Edit a new service: `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/audiostream.service`

Writing in the new file

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Mune Radio 
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/shutdown -h +90
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mplayer http://icy.unitedradio.it/VirginRockClassics.mp3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Step 4**

Enable the new service: `sudo systemctl enable audiostream.service`

**Test**

Let the new web radio with a single station play: `sudo reboot ; exit`

---

If something goes wrong try `sudo systemd-analyze verify audiostream.service` or/and `sudo systemctl status audiostream.service`

Comment: NOT SOLVED
Sounds for 6-8 seconds and then it stops, I think the Raspberry shutdown;. 
I have an idea: as the RP doesn't have a RTC, when it gets to the halt command saying "halt after 90 minutes", it triggers a shutdown AT (time+90 minutes), then the RP connects to the NTP and gets the real time,  detects that the time to shutdown is in thew past and acts as it has to.
That is my felling but I don't have any proof of that.